# Why python script hangs after the main process exited

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I have some time consuming task in a function and i want this function to run even after the main process exited.

Code sample:

```
def do_time_consuming_thing():
    // do time consuming task here
    time.sleep(30)

def worker():
    print "start a child process:"
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_time_consuming_thing,args=())
    p.start()
    print "child pid:%d" % p.pid
    sys.exit(0) // main process exit here.

def test():
    worker()
```

But when i run the above code in shell command line, i can not return to the command line prompt before the child process finishes.

How can i return to the command line prompt immediately after the sys.exit(0) finishes.

Comment: I can use os.fork() to achieve this, but i want to know whether there is a way multiprocessing can do it.

Answer (score 5):

In your code replace your exit line

```
sys.exit(0)
```

with this:

```
os._exit(0)
```

From the python docs:

> os._exit(n)
>
> Exit the process with status n, without calling cleanup handlers, flushing stdio buffers, etc.

I can't say I recommend this approach, but it answers your question if the requirement is to use the multiprocessing module.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `p.daemon = True` before `p.start()`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27495258/3573344).

Comment: It does not work. The child process will terminate immediately after the sys.exit(0) called, as the main process is the only non-daemon process.

Comment: Oh, you want your code to execute in the background and return to the shell while it's executing? Try running `python script.py &` on Linux or osx. I'm not sure how to do it on windows.

Comment: No, i can not use the script in this way.

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24694763/3573344